# Select two columns from two table with conditions

Tags: mysql

I want to

```
 SELECT table1.columnA FROM table1 + ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1; //to get last row
```

and

```
SELECT SUM(table2.columnB) FROM table2
```

and then i want to do a minus condition like

```
SELECT table1.columnA FROM table1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 - SELECT SUM(table2.columnB) FROM table2
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is the result between subtracting the sum of columnB from columnA so use this:

```
SELECT table1.id,table1.columnA -(select sum(columnB) from table2) as YourColumn
FROM Table1
ORDER BY table1.id desc LIMIT 1
```